# Annotation processing for Dagger with Maven

Tags: java, maven, annotations, dagger

I am setuping **Maven** for project that uses **Dagger**, but I can't find good guide about annotation processing setup for **maven-processor-plugin**

Here is part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

but it cant build last module, that refers on injected properties.
target/generated-sources/annotations is empty.
MY IDE - InteliJ IDEA

Sorry, about noob question, but I totally confused. Will be very glad for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using this with success.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm also using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I'm using class `dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcess` for dagger version `1.2.2`, seems `ComponentProcessor` has bee deprecrated